# How to get the split character?

Tags: c#

I need to split a string using any of the operators such as '+' , '-' ,'*', or '/'. How can i append the same to another string while splitting the original one?

For Example : Original string is : `Viewer.Amount + Payment - 100`

```
          Output             : [Viewer.Amount] + [Payment] - 100;
```

I need to wrap the words with [] and thats why im using split. I choose operators as split characters and i need to append those to my final string.

Please Help . Thank You.

Comment: Not very clear. Are you trying to wrap words with `[...]`? You don't seem to be splitting anything...

Comment: Are you trying to eval some code that is provided in a string format?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what you're asking and its not clear from your question.

Comment: I need to wrap the words with [] and thats why im using split. I choose operators as split characters and i need to append those to my final string.

Comment: Not sure about the question - it's a little unclear, but `Regex.Replace` is a good starting point if I understood that much.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this works.

```
string[] values = providedString.Split({'+', '-', '*' /*etc...*/});

string replaced;
string newString;
for(int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    if(Int32.TryParse(value[i], out number))
         continue;

    replaced = "["+values[i]+"]";
    newString = providedString.Replace(values[i], replaced);
}
```

Comment: But i cannot hardcode the values. I'm getting a string input and that could be anything. So how i can i follow the above method?

Comment: Changed example to make the values variable

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to do, so you might want to think about editing your question and being more specific.

But if I had to guess, this will help you retrieve the values in your evaluation.

```
string operation = "[26] + [200] - [100]";
List<string> values = new List<string>();

var items = operation.Split('[');

for (int i = 1; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    values.Add(items[i].Substring(0, items[i].IndexOf(']')));
}

foreach (var value in values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

So with the above you will retrieve, 26, 200 and 100.

Comment: i need both,the values and the split character. Im splitting my string using expression.Split('+','-','*','/'); I'm not able to get the index of the split character dynamically from the multiple list.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use split if I were you.  Instead, use regex replace or maybe just roll your own.  A regex to start with: `([A-Za-z\.]+)`

Answer (score 0):

```
static string Magic(string str)
{
    Regex r = new Regex(@"([A-Za-z\.\d]+)");
    return r.Replace(str, "[$0]");            
}
```

Output: `"[Viewer.Amount] + [Payment] - [100]"`